# Hibernate Criteria API - create automatic join

Tags: java, hibernate, join, criteria-api

I have the following setup

```
Seizure {
   private SeizureI18n seizureI18n;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
   public SeizureI18n getSeizureI18n() {
     return this.seizureI18n;
   }
}

SeizureI18n {
  private Seizure seizure;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "seizureI18n")
  public Seizure getSeizure() {
    return this.seizure;
  }

}
```

When I issue a query with the following `Criteria` query (observe the usage of an alias)

```
 criteria = metaDataConsole.session.createCriteria(Seizure.class,"Seizure");

 criteria.createCriteria("Seizure.seizureI18n");

 criteria.list();
```

it results in the following SQL query.

```
FROM   incbszdb.seizure this_ 
  INNER JOIN incbszdb.seizure_i18n seizurei18x1_ 
ON this_.id = seizurei18x1_.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN incbszdb.seizure seizure4_ 
ON seizurei18x1_.id = seizure4_.id
```

Where does the **second join to seizures**

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN incbszdb.seizure seizure4_ 
ON seizurei18x1_.id = seizure4_.id
```

comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* Hibernate adds this join because, when loading a SeizureI18n, it's unable to know if the SeizureI18n has an associated Seizure or not. So it's unable to know if he must populate the seizure field with null or with a Seizure instance (or proxy to a Seizure instance). Of course, in this particular query, it seems strange. But if you were just loading SeizureI18n without their Seizure, it would feel more normal.

If a SeizureI18n always has an associated Seizure, you should mark the association as non-optional (`optional = false`). I think it should avoid the additional join (since Hibernate would know that there is an associated  Seizure, and that the property is thus never null).

Comment: added ``optional = false`` to SeizureI18n, same query as before, any other ideas?

Comment: The reason, why Hibernate created the second left join was that the assocation between Seizure and SeizureI18n was defined as ``ONE-to-ONE`` which was wrong. I had to change the relationship in the database, recreate the hibernate classes and mapping and Hibernate created the correct ``ONE-to-MANY`` relationship